# Import/read csv file in python, then plotting, gives x=y plot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, matplotlib

This is something that probably has a very obvious fix. I'm using `Python 2.7` and I'm in `Spyder 3.2.4`. I'm trying to plot a very straightforward (albeit large) bit of data from a `csv` file by reading it in and then plotting it. The `csv "df"` is `[6369 rows x 2 columns]`. My problem is that my code below just gives me a `x=y graph` for some reason. If I change the `0's` in the `row[0]` to `1's`, it says `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'`

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', delimiter=',')

x=[]
y=[]

for row in df:
    x.append(int(row[0]))
    y.append(int(row[0]))

plt.plot(x,y,label='csv')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('pls let this work')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[And here is the plot that it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32G3e.png)

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `for row in df:` you iterate over the columns of the dataframe, not the rows. To iterate over the rows, you canuse `for i,row in df.iterrows():`.

Hence a working example could look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[5,3,4,2]})
t.to_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',')

x=[]
y=[]

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    x.append(int(row.values[0]))
    y.append(int(row.values[1]))

plt.plot(x,y,label='csv')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('pls let this work')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The iteration however seems unnecessary. You can just take the columns from the dataframe and plot them directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[5,3,4,2]})
t.to_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',')

plt.plot(df["x"],df["y"],label='csv')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('pls let this work')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Or directly call `plot` on the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[5,3,4,2]})
t.to_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', sep=',')

df.plot(x="x",y="y", label="csv")

plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('pls let this work')
plt.show()
```

Comment: +1 Much better answer than mine (obviously). It does look like you're assuming the OP's csv file has column headings `'x'` and `'y'` though. What if there are no column headings in the file?

Comment: @landogardner I'm not assuming that the column headers are `'x'` and `'y'`; of course if they are different, one needs to adapt their names in the solution. If there are no column headers in the file, you would need to read the csv via `pd.read_csv(..., header=0)`.

Comment: `header=None`, not `header=0` (`header=0` allows you to replace _existing_ names with `names=[...]`)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be `header=None` in case there are no headers in the file of course.

Comment: What you're saying re: dataframes makes sense, but I'm also not sure about "x":[1,2,3,4] and same for y. And no, no headers. The plot looks like this now: https://imgur.com/a/jBRHj for all three examples you gave but the csv file has 6k+ datapoints (astronomy...)

Comment: Yes, this is the intended plot. I'm usually creating [mcve]s in my answers, especially if the OP did not include any. This is to make everything reproducible. What exactly are you unsure about here?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I know the approximate shape that this should be taking, and it's approximately an inverse exponential decay shape. The x values are in the realm of 4.0E+08 and y hovering around 1.5E+028. So I'm just unsure because it's still between 0-5 and looks to only have a handful of points as opposed to the smoother curve that I'm looking for?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what you mean. May I remind you that I don't have `'SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv'` available?! So my plot of course does not look like yours.

Comment: @landogardner `int(1.5E+028)` seems a bit unnecessary, but I don't think it will cause any practical problem and matplotlib will plot such number as expected. (The reason for that, even though it is larger than sys.maxint may be a question by itself, which I cannot answer)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I hope I'm not coming across as rude! Thank you ever so much for all your help so far; I realise you have limited background information and it's my job to provide it if I want help. What I meant is that since I do have that .csv, and that it ought to be importing it, the fact that my plot does look like ^the link I posted in my comment above, that's a sign that something is wrong. On top of that, I don't understand the role of ({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[5,3,4,2]}). Why those numbers in particular?

Comment: Those numbers were the first to come under my fingers when typing. "x" and "y" are just to give columns a name (at that point in time, I did not know that you don't have headers). The fact that your plot looks like mine could be due to you overwriting your original file by running my code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, you're right: the use of `int()` isn't a problem (even though it's unnecessary).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yeah... my original csv data is gone. It's overwritten with those numbers. I'll have to come back to this some other time because I now have to redo everything that got me that data....

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

Assuming your csv file is formatted like this (with no column headings):

```
1E+08,1E+028 
2E+08,4E+028  
3E+08,9E+028
```

You can plot the values using the dataframe itself, without creating any `list`s. In the code below, I've named the columns of the dataframe `'a'` and `'b'`, but you can call them whatever you want as long as you're consistent:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('SDISKSTATS_timeMassDisk.csv', delimiter=',', header=None, names=['a', 'b'])

plt.plot(df['a'], df['b'], label='csv')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('pls let this work')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the difference from the one posted as the question

Comment: Only because you call something `row` doesn't mean that it is a row.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, silly mistake. Editing now.